# Дождаться выполнения функции coroutine

Tags: unity3d

Имею функцию:

```
public int CreateRendVolume(){
... 
    StartCoroutine(WaitFramesAndDo(10, () => a = Summ(a));
            return a;

}
private static IEnumerator WaitFramesAndDo(int frameCount, Action action) {
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
            yield return null;
        action();
    }
```

Как правильно дождаться выполнение Coroutine, чтобы получить значение оттуда?

Comment: Что значит "получить значение оттуда"? Откуда "оттуда"? Из корутины? Корутины не должны ничего возвращать.

Comment: после выполнения функции waitframesanddo

Comment: Еще раз повторю, корутины **ничего не возвращают**, они сделаны не для этого. Ваш код в `CreateRendVolume()` сразу же вернет переменную a. Да и что значит "дождаться выполнения корутины", корутины сделаны для того, чтобы наоборот не ждать и не следить за ними.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дождаться выполнение корутины можно только в другой корутине

```
yield return CoroutineName();
```

В вашем случае в методе CreateRendVolume необходимо будет запустить корутину, которая запустит и дождется выполнения корутины WaitFramesAndDo, и затем уже выполнит код, который необходимо было выполнить после завершения указанный выше корутины.

Как-то так:

```
public int CreateRendVolume()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndDo);
}
private static IEnumerator WaitAndDo()
{
    yield return WaitFramesAndDo(10, () => a = Summ(a));

    //Здесь необходимый код после завершения
    // ... //
    //Если же Вам необходимо именно "вернуть" значение,
    //тогда придется переделать логику на вызов метода,
    //который уже сделает все необходимое с переменной "a",

    //Также, возможно, может пригодиться использование ключевых слов ref/out
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier
}
private static IEnumerator WaitFramesAndDo(int frameCount, Action action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        yield return null;
    action();
}
```